# Locale does not switch while iterating in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, localization, refinerycms, rails-i18n

I have extended RefineryCMS blog/admin/posts controller with Export action, which export post to xml and save it to file. I need export all translated versions of post. When I click export it saves all files, but all files have same locale.

Is it anything wrong with my code:

```
def generate_xml_by_locales
  translated_locales.each do |l|
    ::I18n.locale = l
    file = File.new("blog_#{l}.xml", "wb")
    xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new :target => file
    xml.instruct!
    xml.blog do
      xml.title post.title
      xml.description "Sixteenth installment of development diary"
      xml.language l.to_s
      xml.author "Dan"
      xml.date post.created_at
      xml.category "diary"
      xml.text post.body
    end
    file.close
  end 
end
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did one modification, which work just fine. Instead of changing locale via I18n.locale I use translations.where(locale: lang).first . Don't know if it is the best solution, but it just works.

Refactored code:

```
def generate_xml_by_locales
  translated_locales.each do |lang|
    generate_xml(translations.where(locale: lang).first, lang)
  end
end

def generate_xml post, lang
  file = File.new("blog_#{lang}.xml", "wb")
  xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new :target => file
  xml.instruct!
  xml.blog do
    xml.title post.title
    xml.description "Sixteenth installment of development diary"
    xml.language lang.to_s
    xml.author "Dan"
    xml.date post.created_at
    xml.category "diary"
    xml.text post.body
  end
  file.close
end
```